# Creating copies of spreadsheets with formula links of one of the copies to new copy

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have two spreadsheets, primary and secondary, on my work intranet site. The secondary has formulas that refer to the primary spreadsheet. I want to create a copy of both primary and secondary but need the formulas of the "Copy of secondary" to refer to "Copy of primary" and not to the original primary spreadsheet. Kindly help.

Comment: I think this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847919/simple-excel-find-and-replace-for-formulas

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).